# Current Source Transformation

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, linear

[image]

So my question is: Can I transform the current source I1 with R5 into a voltage source? I know for sure that if R3 was not in between them I could, but does it make a difference? I am not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: If your using thevinin equivalents then move from the outermost to the inner most part of the circuit (start with V2 and V1). This problem would be easier to solve with node voltage or superposition (where you evaluate each source independently)

Comment: No you can't because of the R3 resistor being in the way.

Comment: @laptop2d I actually tried using superposition to solve it but my answer doesn't match the voltages in OrCAD.. For VR2, it would just be two voltage divisions and for I1, two successive current divisions right?

Comment: Superposition is a great solution for this one. For V2, you would have ((R3+R4)+(R1||R2))||R5 = Ra, which leaves you with V2 and two parallel resistors, Ra and R6. Then transform V2 and one of the resistors into a current source, then Ra+R6 = Re. In this particular case, you end up with a current source in series with a resistor, from where it's easy to find the voltage or current. Similarly for I1 and V1. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between a current source and a voltage source is that the current source drives a particular current to the circuit and the voltages build across the components, while a voltage source will supply a voltage that remains constant and the components will pull current based on that voltage. Using Ohm's law and Kirchhoff's equations, we can solve for the voltage or current across each component.

A current source will never be a voltage source, but it will cause a voltage across each component that could be modeled as a voltage source. Use the Thevenin equivalent circuit to model your circuit as a voltage source.

For example, using superposition, you can find a voltage across R5. Then, by shorting the independent voltage sources and current sources, you can find the thevenin resistance at the terminals of R5. This could then be modeled as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffT6N1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT

Sorry, my understanding is very conceptual. I now see you were referring to the analytical tool of source transformation. My understanding is that source transformations can only be used in the special case of a current source in parallel with a resistor, or a voltage source in series with a resister, so R3 would violate those requirements.